# Oracle Apex update specific row of table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hi i want to update a specific row of my oracle database via apex. So i need to reach/address the specific row via where clause.

example entries:

| GATTUNG | ART | UNTERART | ABART | VARIETÄT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | AAA | AAA | NULL | NULL |
| AAA | AAA | NULL | NULL | AAA |
| AAA | AAA | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Now i have two approaches.

first:

```
UPDATE TBL_PFLANZE
SET NAMEN =:P1_NAMEN
WHERE (GATTUNG = :P1_GATTUNG AND ART = :P1_ART_KREUZUNG)
AND ((UNTERART=:P1_UNTERART OR :P1_UNTERART IS NULL) AND (VARIETÄT=:P1_VARIETAET OR :P1_VARIETAET IS NULL) AND (ABART=:P1_ABART OR :P1_ABART IS NULL));
```

second:

```
UPDATE TBL_PFLANZE 
SET NAMEN ='&P1_NAMEN.' 
WHERE (GATTUNG = '&P1_GATTUNG.' AND ART = '&P1_ART_KREUZUNG.') 
AND (UNTERART &P1_WHERE_UNTERART. AND VARIETÄT &P1_WHERE_VARIETAET. AND ABART &P1_WHERE_ABART.);
```

the differences of both approaches are the `P1_WHERE_...`variables.

1. the first one use for example :P1_UNTERART and contains the whole value
2. the second one use for example &P1_WHERE_UNTERART. and contains `= '&P1_UNTERART.'` OR `IS NULL`

my problem is:

1. the first one updates all entries if i only set GATTUNG and ART (if i do not specify one of the other variables)
2. the second will work, but is not the right approach as I should be using binding variables instead of `&VAR.`

So my question is, how can i use the first approach which the desired result... :(

Comment: When `:P1_UNTERART` is null, should it only update when column `UNTERART` is also null? E.g. do you want `(UNTERART=:P1_UNTERART OR (UNTERART IS NULL AND :P1_UNTERART IS NULL))` etc

Comment: @kfinity no, for example I have 3 or 6 or n-entries that are unique in the combination of (GATTUNG + TYPE) + UNTERART + ABART + VARIETÄT. and I always have to be able to update one of the n-combinations.
Therefore:
WHERE UNTERART is null AND ABART is null and VARIETY is null. 
then:
WHERE UNTERART is null AND ABART is null and VARIETÄT = 'STRING' 
next:
WHERE UNTERART is null AND ABART = 'String' and VARIETÄT is null
and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick ? It will update the rows if any of the columns have the same value as the corresponding page item or the database column and page item are both null:

```
UPDATE tbl_pflanze
   SET
  namen = :P1_NAMEN
 WHERE
  ( gattung = :P1_GATTUNG AND art = :P1_ART_KREUZUNG)
    AND
  ( ( NVL(unterart,'X') = NVL(:P1_UNTERART,'X')) AND
    ( NVL(varietät,'X') = NVL(:P1_VARIETAET,'X')) AND
    ( NVL(abart,'X') = NVL(:P1_ABART,'X')) );
```

Comment: it works even if it looks a bit creepy ^^, thanks

Comment: Great. Replace the "X" with something like "novalue" will make it look more professional ;). Can you mark the answer as correct please ?

Comment: Yes that's right. I will do that. I thought there might be other approaches ( for a better understanding :D) . ;) but yes i will mark as correct. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the 1st query is correct while the 2nd is wrong.

Why is it wrong? Because you're using *strings*. This:

```
SET NAMEN ='&P1_NAMEN.' 
WHERE (GATTUNG = '&P1_GATTUNG.'
```

would want to put litally `&P1_NAMEN.` string into the `NAMEN` column for all rows whose `GATTUNG` column contains literally `&P1_GATTUNG.` string in it (and there's most probably none, so the 2nd query won't do anything, ever).

So, what is your problem, exactly? Why do you think that the 1st query doesn't work? Did you run the page in debug mode and reviewed debug results? Could it be that P1 page's items aren't stored into session state so `UPDATE` statement doesn't see them?

Also, where do you execute that `UPDATE`? As a process which runs after button is pressed? Something else?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry, I may have forgotten to explain something. I use dynamic actions and server-side code execution, and I apologize for any misunderstandings.

I know the second approach is wrong, but works as expected: D.
(P1_GATTUNG & P1_ART is set and update only line 3)

The first and correct approach updates all rows when I set P1_GATTUNG and P1_ART.

but due to data integrity I only want to update line 3 if the fields P1_UNTERART, P1_ABART & P1_VARIETÄT are empty or the corresponding fields in the database are NULL. the da is triggered by a button.

Comment: P1_NAMEN and P1_GATTUNG and P1_ART contains a simple string. But for the where clause its important to use IS NULL when the field is empty to get the right row.